# Need working example using jQuery getJSON

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, getjson

I've read many articles online and still don't fully understand how to use this function. This is also my first attempt at using an asynchronous method. Developing a web application in Visual Studio 2010 and need some help with using the getJSON function. I would like use this function to obtain a string from a C# web method. How does this information get passed? What type of object should it be in?

Please provide server and client side code in your response.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I hate to post a simple link as an answer but since SO is not a free coding service, I feel compelled to have you do your homework.

[Here's an example of what you need.](http://encosia.com/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

.getJSON is just like any other AJAX request, except it assumes the data it receives will be in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/js.html).

If you're new to this format, read the docs and practice using [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com); the format is very strict in how things must be formatted and things like trailing commas that JavaScript allows aren't permitted in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm also new to coding AJAX requests, do you have any working examples or tips for getting started?

Comment: @G18Programmer I would start with the jQuery method docs and learn from their examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have read through that page in the past but, I've only been able to find client side code. I not sure what needs to be done on the server side C#. Thanks again.